# Error while trying to load all provider config settings

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting an error message "Error while trying to load all provider config settings" from "ProjectsConfigUtils(22382)" from setContentView. This is on 4.1.2. Any idea what this means? There does not appear to be any discussion of this error anywhere.